# Handling POST request in Wai/Warp in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-wai, haskell-warp

I have a wai/warp application. How can I handle a post request? I have this:

```
app :: Application
app request respond = 
    respond $ case rawPathInfo request of
        "/"  -> responseFile status200 ............
        "/some_post_req/" -> .....
```

How can I specify that `some_post_req` must be POST?

Comment: I see a `requestMethod` function in `Network.Wai` - would you be able to match on that result?

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as comparing the result of `Network.Wai.requestMethod` against `Network.Wai.methodPost`:

```
app request respond
  | requestMethod request == methodPost
  = respond $ case rawPathInfo request of
    {- handle POST routes -}

  | otherwise
  = {- handle other request methods -}
```

Since there are constants for `methodPost`, `methodGet`, &c., you might as well use them, but `Method` is an alias for `ByteString`, so you could also use the `OverloadedStrings` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
```

And then either compare with a string literal:

```
requestMethod request == "POST"
```

Or pattern match:

```
case requestMethod request of
  "POST" -> {- … -}
  "GET" -> {- … -}
  …
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseRequestBody` in the [`wai-extra`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-extra-3.0.19.1/docs/Network-Wai-Parse.html) package allows you to get the data you want out of the body of the request:

```
(params, files) <- parseRequestBody lbsBackEnd request
```

But this does nothing to specify that the request must be a `POST` request. Keep in mind that `wai` can be pretty low level, and there are higher level packages out there.

[`servant`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant) comes to mind as a package that allows you to define APIs at the type level. With servant, you definitely can specify the HTTP verb you expect. See [here](http://haskell-servant.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/ApiType.html).